# How to translate this query to Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am not sure about the inner SQL inside `time_diff` method:

```
SELECT t1.started_at as chain_break,
time_to_sec(timediff(t1.started_at,IFNULL(
                                          (SELECT MAX(t2.ended_at)
                                           FROM status_records t2
                                           WHERE t2.user_id=189
                                           AND t2.started_at< t1.started_at
                                          ), t1.started_at
                                        )
                        )
                ) / 3600 AS time_off 
FROM status_records t1 
WHERE t1.user_id=189 
ORDER BY t1.ended_at DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

Is there a nice way to do it except putting this query in `DB::query` as raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, you can use [`selectRaw()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectRaw) to add your subquery as a field selection. To create the subquery, you can create another query builder.

Comment: How would you use `selectRaw` to achieve same results as my query?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DB::raw("SELECT t1.started_at as chain_break,
time_to_sec(timediff(t1.started_at,IFNULL(
                                          (SELECT MAX(t2.ended_at)
                                           FROM status_records t2
                                           WHERE t2.user_id=189
                                           AND t2.started_at< t1.started_at
                                          ), t1.started_at
                                        )
                        )
                ) / 3600 AS time_off 
FROM status_records t1 
WHERE t1.user_id=189 
ORDER BY t1.ended_at DESC 
LIMIT 6");
```

Comment: Lol. Thanks but I am looking for a way to do it in Laravel style not using a raw query, if possible.